# Origine dell'espressione "una gatta da pelare"

Tags: idioms, phrase-origin

Nel romanzo *La testa perduta di Damasceno Monteiro* di Antonio Tabucchi ho letto:

> «Sono già tutti qua, disse, freschi freschi, Francisca è andata a comprarli alle otto, è un bello scandalo, ne parla tutta la stampa, il Titânio ha proprio una bella *gatta da pelare*, se non c'eravate voi giornalisti la polizia in quei locale non ci sarebbe mai andata, per fortuna c'è  la stampa.»

Ho trovato che, in questo contesto, una [gatta da pelare](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/G/gatto.shtml#14) significa una incombenza fastidiosa, un problema, un guaio o una situazione difficile. Mi domando, però, quale sia l'origine di questa curiosa espressione.

Comment: Una non-risposta, giusto per completezza: il *Dizionario dei modi di dire della lingua italiana* di Carlo Lapucci (Garzanti-Vallardi), dopo aver spiegato il significato di questo modo di dire, conclude «Non si sa con precisione a cosa faccia riferimento questo detto».

Comment: Un tempo usavano togliere il pelo ai gatti per creare tessuti e imbottiture, ma risultava essere un'attività difficile perché i gatti si divincolavano e graffiavano. Quindi era un problema serio togliere il pelo a un gatto. L'attività è ancora praticata in Cina.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider Credo che quello che tu stai suggerendo sia difficile a prescindere dal tipo di animale. Infatti prima si uccide l'animale e poi lo si spella (anche per evitargli tutto il dolore...). Se vuoi fornirla come risposta devi fornire delle fonti attendibili sul fatto che ciò sia mai stato fatto, in maniera usuale, con i gatti *vivi*. Inoltre manca da spiegare perchè si dica *gatta* invece del neutro *gatto*. Si spellavano solo i gatti femmina?

Comment: Neanche io ho una risposta precisa, però ho sempre pensato questo detto come qualcosa di volutamente iperbolico. Per la mia sensibilità non ci leggo dentro un'origine contadina, ma ci vedo una scenetta tragicomica in cui un tizio con un coltello in mano prova a pelare una gatta viva, con poco successo.

Comment: Secondo me si fa riferimento ad una gatta femmina invece che ad un gatto perché normalmente (non so quanto a ragione) si attribuisce alla femmina maggiore aggressività a causa del fatto che deve difendere i piccoli. Oppure di tratta del banale spunto ironico secondo il quale le donne (anche nel mondo animale) sarebbero più lunatiche ed intrattabili degli uomini.

Comment: Un paio di link interessanti: http://genio.virgilio.it/domanda/168381/perche-si-dice-gatta-pelare e http://perunaselvaoscura.wordpress.com/2011/06/07/more-than-one-way-to-skin-a-cat-avere-una-bella-gatta-da-pelare/. Però, ancora una volta, nessuna risposta certa e convincente.

Comment: Il modo di dire si riferisce all'antica consuetudine di usare la pelle del gatto selvatico, (felis sylvestris), molto simile al soriano domestico e oggi specie a rischio di estinzione in Italia, per farne pellicce, e alla difficoltà di catturare l'animale, sfuggente e furbo, senza rovinare il manto. L'uso del termine “gatta” deriva dall'uso della lingua antica, (tuttora diffuso al sud), di indicare al femminile il felino, senza determinazione di sesso, come ad esempio la lince o la pantera.http://ersiliogallimberti.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/modi-di-dire-anno-bisesto-anno-funesto.html

Comment: @Josh6 Il tuo commento appare meritevole di essere convertito in una risposta, sì.

Comment: FYI: "gatta da pelare" compare davvero spesso anche in "avere [ben] altre gatte da pelare", perfetto corrispettivo di "have other fish to fry".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questa è una domanda più complessa di quanto sembri.

Innanzitutto, perché una gatta e non un gatto? Come giomasce molto correttamente suggerisce, è folklore che le gatte siano più irritabili, più sornione e, se allarmate, più aggressive dei gatti; con probabile ammiccamento all'analoga idea esistente sul conto delle donne. Inoltre tutti sanno che le gatte sono streghe sotto mentite spoglie, no?

Significativamente in inglese esiste l'espressione idiomatica *"There are more ways than one to skin a cat"*: cioè *"esistono tanti modi diversi per fare una cosa difficile"*. L'utente Callithumpian, [qui](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32123/origin-of-the-phrase-theres-more-than-one-way-to-skin-a-cat), ha trovato un'espressione simile datata *1712*: *"Well! more ways may be found than one, To kill a Witch that Will not drown"*, cioè letteralmente *"Beh, c'è più di un modo per uccidere una strega che non riesci ad affogare"*. Wow!

Va poi ricordato come la gatta sia un'assidua frequentatrice di [proverbi italiani](http://aforismi.dossier.net/proverbi-italiani/proverbi1691.htm). Anche al maschile plurale, [i gatti](http://aforismi.dossier.net/proverbi-italiani/proverbi1692.htm) hanno spesso a che fare con le donne.

---

Il manto dei gatti veniva usato per ricavarne pellicce: vi era la credenza che i gatti venissero spellati, scuoiati vivi. [Qualcuno](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32123/origin-of-the-phrase-theres-more-than-one-way-to-skin-a-cat) persino sostiene di aver assistito ad una simile scena. Apparentemente occorre spellare l'animale in fretta in quanto sembra che, dopo la morte, la pelle si irrigidisca rapidamente rendendo il compito molto difficoltoso.

In italiano *pelare una gatta* potrebbe non avere necessariamente lo stesso significato truculento ma potrebbe semplicemente significare toglierle il *pelo* (non la pelle!), nel senso di tosarglielo, e forse anche lavarglielo e pettinarglielo. L'espressione idiomatica si riferirebbe pertanto all'idea che i gatti non amino questo tipo di attenzioni e reagiscano disperatamente graffiando con gli artigli ([qui](http://www.wikihow.com/Bathe-a-Cat) e [qui](http://www.wikihow.com/Shave-a-Cat) qualche idea in proposito).

È peraltro vero che *pelare* può, per estensione, significare anche *spellare, scuoiare*. Quindi forse potrebbe anche voler dire scuoiarla viva, la povera gatta. E *viva* non significa necessariamente *vigile, cosciente*. (Detto per inciso questa è anche la mia opinione personale)

---

Nella 4º edizione del Vocabolario degli accademici della Crusca (1729-1738) [si legge](http://www.lessicografia.it/PELARE):

> «Pelar l'orso; si dice figuratam. e in modo basso, di Cosa, che abbia in se gran polso, e gagliardía»

Nell'edizione del 1829 del *Dictionnaire des idiotismes italiens-français et français-italiens* di Giacomo Polesi, a pagina 267, [si legge](http://books.google.it/books?id=BYUCAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA267&dq=gatta+da+pelare&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RPQtVPbJHtChoQTV0IGADQ&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=gatta%20da%20pelare&f=false):

> «[Tailler] des croupières à quelqu'un. *Dar gatta da pelare ad alcuno. Dar briga*»

Segnalo che i commenti su contengono vari riferimenti utili di cui mi sono servito per rispondere.

Comment: "Tailler des croupières à quelqu'un" significa mettere in difficoltà, mettere nei guai, creare problemi a qualcuno.

Comment: @Charo Grazie per l'integrazione! Ho messo il verbo tra parentesi quadre, visto che nella fonte compare qualche riga prima. Dare a qualcuno una gatta da pelare significa esattamente assegnargli un compito arduo e non piacevole.

Comment: Uno spazio del MACRO di Roma, ex mattatoio di Testaccio, si chiama "la pelanda", ed era il luogo dove si scuoiavano gli animali.